# What feature to enable in windows-rs for OutputDebugStringW?

Tags: rust, windows-rs

I'd like to use `OutputDebugStringW` in windows-rs but it cannot be found in any scope. I tried [searching the repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fwindows-rs%20OutputDebugStringW&type=code) but the only reference is in kernel32.dll.c.

What feature do I need to enable to use `OutputDebugStringW`?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/5c5c82aed3cacfbb83f6dd27c58add883157221f/crates/libs/sys/src/Windows/Win32/System/Diagnostics/Debug/mod.rs#L173

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the documentation for the latest release (0.52.0) that no longer lists the required features. Consider dropping an issue with the [repository](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/).

Comment: Should be either or all of `"Win32_System_Diagnostics_Debug"`, `"Win32_System_Diagnostics"`, `"Win32_System"`, `"Win32"` see [docs on `Debug`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Diagnostics/Debug/index.html) and it's parent modules

Comment: Odd that the Win32_System_Diagnostics_Debug mod.rs does not come up in the search results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The feature to bring in the module that provides `OutputDebugStringW` is `"Win32_System_Diagnostics_Debug"`.

The required features are listed in the documentation published [here](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/). The latest version (0.52.0), however, changed things, and the requirements are no longer listed (in full) near the API call documentation (see this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2717) for more information).

To find the feature that introduces an API, go to the [official documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/), search for the name, follow the link, and move up to the containing module (available from the link in the top left corner). The module documentation will list the required features.

This is hoping that this answer will be ephemeral and the changes be reverted to how things were before.

Comment: I tried searching the repo (see link in original question) and it doesn't find the definition in the module, so there's really no easy way to find this (maybe an edge case).